How to get unique entries in a datatool database in two columns?
This is similiar but different to Obtain unique values of multiple specific columns from a datatool database.
My MWE is
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{data.csv}
room,table
301,A
301,A
301,B
301,C
302,D
302,A
303,A
303,B
303,B
303,C
303,C
\end{filecontents}

\DTLloaddb{department}{data.csv}

\newcommand*{\uniqueRooms}{}
\newcommand*{\uniqueTables}{}
\DTLnewdb{uniqueRoomsAndTables}
\DTLforeach*{department}
{\room=room,
  \table=table%
}{%
  \DTLifSubString{\uniqueRooms}{\room}%
  {% do nothing, already in list
  }%
  {% add to list
    \DTLifSubString{\uniqueRooms}{\room}%
  {% do nothing, already in list
  }%
  {}
    \DTLnewrow{uniqueRoomsAndTables}%
    {\dtlexpandnewvalue\DTLnewdbentry{uniqueRoomsAndTables}{room}{\room}}%
    \eappto\uniqueRooms{\room : }%
    \dtlexpandnewvalue\DTLnewdbentry{uniqueRoomsAndTables}{table}{\table}
  \eappto\uniqueTables{\table : }
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\DTLdisplaydb{uniqueRoomsAndTables}
\end{document}

This is the result:

But I want it to be like:
room  table
301   A
301   B
301   C
302   A
302   D
303   A
303   B
303   C

In other words: the combination of room and table should be unique.

You have to combine the elements room and table into a new key (say) roomtable that you then use as your unique identifier to check for duplicates.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{data.csv}
room,table
301,A
301,A
301,B
301,C
302,D
302,A
303,A
303,B
303,B
303,C
303,C
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{department}{data.csv}

\DTLnewdb{uniqueRoomsAndTables}
\newif\ifduplicatefound
\DTLforeach*{department}{%
  \Room=room,
  \Table=table%
}{%
  \duplicatefoundfalse
  % Cycle through uniqueRoomsAndTables database to check for any duplicates
  \DTLforeach*{uniqueRoomsAndTables}{%
    \RoomTable=roomtable%
  }{%
    % Identify a duplicate
    \DTLifstringeq{\Room\Table}{\RoomTable}{\duplicatefoundtrue}{}%
  }%
  % If no duplicates were found, add entry to uniqueRoomsAndTables
  \ifduplicatefound\else
    \dtlexpandnewvalue
    \DTLnewrow{uniqueRoomsAndTables}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{uniqueRoomsAndTables}{roomtable}{\Room \Table}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{uniqueRoomsAndTables}{room}{\Room}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{uniqueRoomsAndTables}{table}{\Table}%
    \dtlnoexpandnewvalue
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\DTLdisplaydb{department}

% Display uniqueRoomsAndTable (dropping roomtable)
\DTLdisplaydb[roomtable]{uniqueRoomsAndTables}

\end{document}

